# When SSL directives takes effect

Tags: apache2, mod-ssl

I'm trying to learn the basics of Apache server configuration, and wondering about SSL directives validity among different scopes on Apache.

Those directives;

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key"
SSLRequireSSL ...
```

Where can they be placed? Only in VirtualHost section? If I put these in the global scope, will they work?

Sorry if this question is off context somehow, I still have some comprehensive issues with Apache :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Apache! The first lesson is to learn how to read the excellent documentation. In the Apache documentation, every directive has a [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) section that indicates where in the server's configuration files the directive is legal. It can be found right below the `Syntax:` and `Default:` lines.

> **server config** This means that the directive may be used in the server
> configuration files (e.g., `httpd.conf`), but not within any
> `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` containers. It is not allowed in
> `.htaccess` files at all.
>
> **virtual host** This context means that the directive may appear inside
> `<VirtualHost>` containers in the server configuration files.
>
> **directory** A directive marked as being valid in this context may be
> used inside `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>`, `<If>`, and `<Proxy>`
> containers in the server configuration files, subject to the
> restrictions outlined in Configuration Sections.
>
> **.htaccess** If a
> directive is valid in this context, it means that it can appear inside
> per-directory .htaccess files. It may not be processed, though
> depending upon the overrides currently active.

With [`SSLEngine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslengine), [`SSLCertificateFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile), [`SSLCertificateKeyFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatekeyfile) the contexts are server config & virtual host. This means you could specify them for the whole server and also override this default configuration per `<VirtualHost>`.

The [`SSLRequireSSL` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequiressl) on the other hand is legal in directory & .htaccess contexts. This means you can, by placing this in a directory, specify that non-TLS connections shouldn't be allowed even if there exists a HTTP alone virtual hosts that would otherwise serve this directory.

However, this day and age you should protect everything with TLS, making `SSLRequireSSL` needless. Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS & enforce it by a *HTTP Strict Transport Security* (HSTS) policy ([RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent answer! Understanding the documentation was exactly what I needed.